# How to save google search's images?

Tags: python, google-api

I want to save the first three images of a Google Images Search to my local drive.
For that, I need an API. Google has the [Google Image Search API](https://developers.google.com/image-search/), but it seems that it's deprecated now.

1. Is there an alternative for it?
2. If not, is it against Google's TOS to parse the webpage itself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/) now instead.  And here's a [starting point](http://support.google.com/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1210656).

Hope that helps.